# GLSL Black to white transition

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've seen this effect many times before, but on a lot smaller scale. Now I have a long wall. It starts as white and gradually turns to black when you're reaching it's back. And as the transition goes, it appears that wall is divided by some vertical lines.
[image]

The effect is more visible from up close:
[image]

Why is this happening and is there a way to fix this, to make transition as smooth as possible with no visible lines? My wall is made of ~78 vertices, and they are placed only at the corners of wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is known as [Colour_banding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding). Simply there is not enough color resolution to express the grey gradient in 8 bits. You might try dithering.